# Magento 2 How to create Hero image module to CMS page

Tags: magento2, cms-block, cms-pages

[image]

I have created the hero image module for the CMS page. But the image is not uploaded and there is issue to save the image too. Is there any solution for that?

please suggest.

Comment: Have you used any extension? Does its error log generate any error?

Comment: no i have created my own module @Agilox

Comment: Check this solution: [https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/206834/84555](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/206834/84555) It may help you.

Comment: I have already gone through it but image upload is not working as above image